What is this mojibake'd book signature "A±4÷, A -Z±8÷," etc?
On this page of metadata about a holding of the Biblioteca Nacional, I find this text:

Sign.: A±4÷, A -Z±8÷, Aa -Ii±8÷ KK±8÷, Ll -Rr±8÷. A -Q±8÷, R±6÷

And here's some more:

Sign.: []±1÷, *±6÷, A±6÷, B -Z±8÷, 2A -2F±8÷

My guess is that this is mojibake — I think the ÷ character (Unicode U+00F7) is supposed to be º (Unicode U+00BA), so that e.g. 4÷ means "4º" means "quarto," and "Sign." stands for "signature" in the sense of "paper size."
But I can't figure out what the ± (Unicode U+00B1) is supposed to mean, nor any of the rest of the cryptic abbreviations!
The easiest way to answer this is probably to know about books and bookbinding, so that you just know what character belongs there (and then please explain what that abbreviation means in this context). The second-easiest way is if you can figure out the intended non-UTF-8 encoding, that caused the mojibake'ing of º into ÷; then you can reverse it to figure out the correct character, even if you're as clueless as I am about its meaning in this context.

Have you tried contacting the Biblioteca Nacional and asking them? there's a contact form in the site you linked. They will definitely know what that's supposed to be.

@Luciano: That's a good idea, given the lack of replies here so far. I just filled out the contact form, and will update here if I get a reply (and if the question is still open, since I don't think it will be possible to comment on it nor answer it if it ends up getting closed — that's one of the downsides of StackOverflow's moderation system).

The problem is that your question is not really about design or book editing; maybe something a web developer could know but most probably only answerable by the site publisher. Hence the lack of answers here.

@Luciano: first, thanks! (see my new answer below) — and yeah, this question isn't about web design, but as far as I know it's about bookbinding, which is at least adjacent to typography, and this SE has a lot of typography material. I guess it'd be a better fit for a "Library Science" SE, if such a thing existed. (SE's tragic flaw, IMO, is its balkanization — it expects both questioners and answerers to juggle a million tiny siloed SEs instead of just a few big hubs.)

The question is not about bookbinding per se, it's essentially about an issue with character encoding on a website. It's a very localized problem and the characters could mean anything. But I'm glad you found an answer!

@Luciano: Read the question (and BNE's partial answer) again — it's not about character encoding after all, and the meaning of the abbreviations is still unknown as of this writing.

Thanks to @Luciano's suggestion that I submit a comment to the BNE, I did that; and this morning I received a response that gives a partial answer to my original question. The librarian writes (in part):

The cause of those "strange" characters appearing in the description was caused by a character set compliance problem while entering the data in the bibliographic system. The line should read like this:
Sign.: A⁴, A-Z⁸, Aa-Ii⁸, KK⁸, Ll-Rr⁸. A-Q⁸, R⁶

So it looks like my guess about 8÷ meaning 8º = 8vo = octavo was incorrect after all.
I've replied to their reply, thanking them and asking, okay, so what do these abbreviations actually mean in this context? I'll update again if I find out.
